# Unlock folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, directory, locking, file-access

I have an .exe and when I run it some files in one directory are being locked. I also have possibility in this .exe to rename that folder, and when I want to rename it of course I get the error that some files are being locked. Actually I have two questions:
1) What functionality causes files to lock? I mean could, for example, FileAccess enum affects to this?
2) How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the application doing with the files?

Comment: A locked file doesn't prevent it from being renamed.  The somewhat more likely problem here is that the *directory* is locked.  Doesn't happen often, but certainly possible if it is the default directory of a program.  Like yours.  Keep an eye on Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you open a stream (or a writer / reader, which wrap a stream), that locks the file.

You need to close your streams using the `using` statement.

Comment: So it means that even if I close writer/reader, file stays locked?

Comment: @Viaches: No; closing the reader or writer will also close the underlying stream.  (unless you pass a special ctor parameter that tells it not to)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What functionality causes files to lock?

This is caused because some process (potentially your program) has a file opened and locked, preventing other processes from manipulating it.

> 2) How can I fix this problem?

Make sure no process, including your own, keeps the files open when you try to perform the rename.  This typically means making sure you always close your file streams, which can be handled automatically via the [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) when you create or open your files.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to make it clear...Can file be closed and locked? Because I've made kind of reviews of my code and I haven't found any pieces of code where I forgot to close file stream

Comment: @Viaches No - but the file can be locked by a different program.

Comment: I use Unlocker to see what program is locking files and it is only my application. I guess I need to review my code one more time